# can we assign the values of a class object values to that vector class?

Tags: c++, vector

I am using a vector named student vector and the associated class name is  student
I have declare the student as 
student s1;
can we assign the value like this 
studentvector[1]=s1;
?????

Comment: Please show us some code: declarations of the variables, definition of the types...

Comment: `studentvector[1]=s1;` this can only be done if the vector already allocated elements e.g. using `resize()`. Otherwise you'll have to use `studentvector.push_back(s1);`

Comment: Is code necessary ???

Comment: @naveentyagi Code is almost always necessary. It's very hard to make sense of your question without it, and it shows what you have tried (and that you *have* tried).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether the class has the default constructor. If so then you can write

```
std::vector<student> studentvector( 2 );
student s1;

studentvector[1] = s1;
```

Take into account that indices start from 0.

If the class does not have the default constructor then you can use method push_back. For example

```
std::vector<student> studentvector;
studentvector.reserve( 2 );

student s0( /* some arguments */ );
student s1( /* some arguments */ );

studentvector.push_back( s0 ); 
studentvector.push_back( s1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

What, like this?

```
student s1;
std::vector<student> studentvector;
studentvector.push_back(s1);
```

... or like this?

```
student s1;
std::vector<student> studentvector(10);
studentvector[1]=s1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: provide some code.

Answering your question: it depends on how many elements there are in vector. If there are two or more, then assigning like this is ok:

```
studentvector[1] = s1; //OK if there are at least two elements in studentvector
```

In other case you need to add it, for example with push_back.

Comment: Assuming there is an `operator=` for `student`, of course.